# delete list items from 0 to 100

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to delete a list index from 0 to given variable in this case 500, from a file and save it to another file.

```
    # list to store file lines
    linesr = []
    num = 500

    with open('in.txt', 'r') as ftpr: 
        # read an store all lines into list
        linesr = ftpr.readlines()
        with open('out.txt', 'w') as ftpw:
            for number, line in enumerate(linesr):
                for x in range(1, num):  
                    if number not in [x]:
                        ftpw.write(str(linesr))
```

in this case the first 500 lines from in.txt should be ignored and the rest from the file written to out.txt. The program hangs without given any error. What am i doing wrong.Thanks.

Comment: Just see the title is to 100 instead 500

Answer (score 0):

Just slice your list and write that.

```
# list to store file lines
linesr = []
num = 500

with open('in.txt', 'r') as ftpr: 
    # read an store all lines into list
    linesr = ftpr.readlines()
with open('out.txt', 'w') as ftpw:
    ftpw.write('\n'.join(linesr[num:]))
```